# How to include executables in the IntelliJ IDEA path for successful pre-committing?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a Git pre-commit hook that runs a Grunt command. However, Grunt is not on the path that IDEA runs under, so when I try to commit through the IDE I get a `grunt: command not found` error.

How can I ensure that Grunt is available to IDEA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this is because `/usr/local/bin` wasn't on the `PATH` (in OSX). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17557522/555642.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue and then I executed the `npm install`. Thereafter I was able to run the grunt commands. Tryout and see this might fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks. This won't do it though, `npm install` [puts `Grunt` in your system path](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#installing-the-cli). I can run it from the command line, as expected, but IDEA can't.